# AWS Lambda - Double trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, triggers, aws-lambda

For some reason i see the triggers for my lambda function as double. If i delete one both are deleted and if i add 1 two are added.

[image]

The real problem is that i think this is making it fire twice per event so its not just a graphical problem.
Any ideas?

I also tried removing the trigger and adding it from the s3 console but i had no luck.

Comment: I have the same issue. But I was defining triggers with Serverless Framework. Try creating the trigger from that Lambda Console directly and it wont be double. But if your lambda is firing more than one then it might be failing with an exception and might be retried. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578619/lambda-processing-same-sns-event-multiple-times/37579191#37579191